# Flex Wrap not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

The following code doesn't seem to wrap up my content.
I have made all possible changes to my code but can't seem to find a workable solution.
In fact, it seems the browser is not responding to the wrap setting.
Thanks in advance.
I am working on a news website. I have an article. A small write up along with an image will be the main banner of the website. To make the website responsive, I need to wrap up the write up.

```css
.mainArticle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.left,
.right {
  /*float: left;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  /*flex-shrink: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;*/
  padding: 30px;
}

.right {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /*display: block;*/
  /* flex-grow: 0;
 flex-shrink: 0;*/
}

.right img {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px rgba(242, 125, 12, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  /*display: block;*/
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#heading {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#subHeading {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 22.5px;
}

#detail {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#readMore {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f27d0c;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f27d0c;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainBody">
  <div class="mainArticle">
    <div class="left">
      <h1 id="heading">From The Desk of Director</h1>
      <h5 id="subHeading">Excerpt from an interview with Dr. b. k. mishra, director, iit goa</h5>
      <p id="detail">Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id
        euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
      <a id="readMore" href="#">Read More>> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="Images/sample.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lineBelowArticle"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: What will be your breakpoint. Your flex isnt wraping, because you have a 50% width declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `width: 50%` for `.left, right`, which basically tells browser to shrink elements to 50% no matter what actual width parent container has. You need to specify these values and then `flex-wrap` will work just fine. It is also required to remove `height: 100%` from `.mainArticle`, and move exact value to `.left, .right` (if you want to use it). If no `height` is provided `.left, right` will adapt to their children (as below).

```css
.mainArticle {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.left,
.right {
  /*float: left;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 600px;
}

.left {
  /*flex-shrink: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;*/
  padding: 30px;
}

.right {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /*display: block;*/
  /* flex-grow: 0;
 flex-shrink: 0;*/
}

.right img {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px rgba(242, 125, 12, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  /*display: block;*/
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#heading {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#subHeading {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 22.5px;
}

#detail {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#readMore {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f27d0c;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f27d0c;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainBody">
  <div class="mainArticle">
    <div class="left">
      <h1 id="heading">From The Desk of Director</h1>
      <h5 id="subHeading">Excerpt from an interview with Dr. b. k. mishra, director, iit goa</h5>
      <p id="detail">Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id
        euismod egestas. Pellentesque sapien ac quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit nullam.</p>
      <a id="readMore" href="#">Read More>> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="Images/sample.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lineBelowArticle"></div>

</section>
```